# Magento Add to Cart button not working

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, debugging

Hi I recently installed **Magento 1.9.2.4**.

Everything is working fine **except the cart button functionality**. When I click the "Add to Cart" button on product details page, nothing is happening.

I **tested with firebug**. I **found that** when I click the button a class, `validation-passed`, is added to the button and **no ajax is calling** against the button click (found in firebug console). **How to find the error behind this?** Please help to debug the error.

Comment: What are you using for ajax cart could you please explain more. Please check console, is there any jquery error?

Comment: You may have problem with session, you use 3rd party extension, please update more detail

Comment: What type of update you need?